# Cannot create file in pycharm

Tags: python, django, pycharm

I'm trying to create a file in pycharm. I get an error 'Cannot create file'. I tried restarting pycharm too. I get the same error. This happens not only while creating python files, but any other type of file too.

[image: The first image is what my project folder looks like.]

[image: The second image is the error I got]

Comment: You already have file urls.py, why do you want to create it again?

Comment: @charitha-reddy The project path is pointing to the operating system directory `C:\Windows\System32`, that's restricted directory for system files, instead you should create your project in your User's path, probably something in `C:\Users\<YourUserName>\Projects\` or similar

Comment: @charithareddy very welcome, glad you fixed it.

Comment: @chiragsoni Thank you. Will try it for sure.

Answer (score 1):

**I had the same issue, but I solved it this way:**

1. Find your project and right-click on it
2. Select properties and go to the security tab
3. Click edit and allow full control
4. Restart pycharm

It should be fixed!

Answer (score 1):

There must be some temporary files in that directory related to windows something like "$ type and some other files" delete those, fixed the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

Bro don't go to search the properties if you are using the window 11 then it will be the driver problem in that
So go into the notepad and create a python file and cut and copy paste that file in to that file were the pycham project is running to there
Step 1 open a notepad file and create a python file in the desktop and name it
Step 2 cut and paste were the main code is there were your pycham project file is there.
Step 3 after that it will
It happens because that Direct want a permission from adminstrator in windows 11 for d drive.

Comment: Language is not formal

Answer (score 0):

As kamkaze_coder said, there must be something related to temporary files or some other similar issue. The solution for me was Just to create a new file with a different name.

I have windows 10